# python3: how to plot hist figure by two list data with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have two data list data value(each 100 numbers) d1 = [0.5, 0.6, 0.45, ........], d2= [0.45,0.65, ........]. I want to plot the two hist with two list data, like the following figure! How to plot it with matplotlib, Thanks!
      my code is following:

```
def plot_data(d1, d2):
   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   ax.hist(d1, 100,  50, ec='red', fc='none', lw=1.5, histtype='step', label='n-gram')
   ax.hist(d2, 100, 50, ec='green', fc='none', lw=1.5, histtype='step', label='ensemble')
   ax.legend(loc='upper left')
  plt.show()
```

but there is error:

```
mn, mx = [mi + 0.0 for mi in range]
TypeError: 'int' object is not utterable
```

[image: two hist with two data lists]

Comment: where is this code that's giving you error.

Comment: What @harshil9968 is saying is that there is no evidence in what you showed us that the error has anything to do with plotting such data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error comes from the third argument to the `hist()` function. [Read the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist) for `hist()`:

> Parameters:    x : (n,) array or sequence of (n,) array (...)
>
> bins : integer or array_like, optional (...)
>
> range : tuple or None, optional
>
> The lower and upper range of the bins. Lower and upper outliers are
>   ignored. If not provided, range is (x.min(), x.max()). Range has no
>   effect if bins is a sequence.**
>
> If bins is a sequence or range is specified, autoscaling is based on
>   the specified bin range instead of the range of x.
>
> Default is None

The third parameter must be either a `tuple` or `None` and you've provided 50 (an `int`).

see the code below, where I simply replaced the 3rd argument by `None` (and reduced the number of bins)

```
d1 = np.random.normal(size=(100,))
d2 = 1+np.random.normal(size=(100,))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(d1, 10, None, ec='red', fc='none', lw=1.5, histtype='step', label='n-gram')
ax.hist(d2, 10, None, ec='green', fc='none', lw=1.5, histtype='step', label='ensemble')
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark on the left